# How to add variable tax on products in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**TAX VARIATION FOR DIFFERENT PRODUCTS**

how to add 2 products with different tax rates in woocommerce?

**Note of no use: irrelevant to question coz of StackOverFlow rules.**

Correctly, setting per-item tax rates should be possible if you register the products yourself in the PayPal website interface. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, because the products are entered by the end user on my CMS.

If what I want isn't possible with a Website Payments Standard button, I would also welcome other ideas on how to forward such orders to PayPal. I am trying to avoid the Express Checkout payment product because if I understand correctly I won't have full control of the cart. I want to have a custom cart and later be able to offer more payment options besides PayPal.

Comment: Have a look on this. https://www.wpdesk.net/blog/woocommerce-taxes-complete-tutorial/ 
Probably this is what you want. Not so sure.

Comment: Sir, i have already done this. What I need is : I need to set different tax price for different products.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tax-rates-for-different-products-being-charged-for-all-products/

Comment: just now... i have seen this link... i m thinking of something custom we can set on each product page..where we can add tax per product . and show that tax included price in cart. is it possible ?

Comment: Probably not, i think that is the best idea to create classes having different rates. Still you can submit a ticket to woocommerce but make sure to explain the requirements properly.
https://woocommerce.com/contact-us/

Comment: Thank you sir :) :)